# Excluding tag Link from html tags in Post content

Tags: wordpress

Please I want to achieve the goal of excluding `<h2>, <a> and <img>` html tag from the below code. I am trying to replace tags keywords with links within post content, and exclude the tag link from affecting the html tags i listed above.

```
function link_words( $text ) {
                $tags = get_tags();
                if ( $tags ) {
                    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
                        $from = '/' . $tag->name . '/';
                        $to = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ), esc_html( $tag->name ) );
                        $text = preg_replace($from, $to , $text, 2);
                    }
                }
                return $text;
            }
            add_filter( 'the_content', 'link_words' );
```

Please Gurus in the house, is there any way out. I am new to wp function coding.

Answer (score 0):

For simple HTML, you can do a str_replace:

```
$text = str_replace(array("<h2>","</h2>"), "", $text);
```

To strip those more complicated tags:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/<a\s[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
```

I just tested the code below and it appears to work:

```
function link_words( $text ) {

    $text = str_replace(array("<h2>","</h2>","</a>"), "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/<a\s[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
    return $text;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'link_words' );
```

Comment: Can you please help me implement it on the OP code ? I am new to wp coding please.

Comment: I've tested and rewritten that function for you - this should work now. If that helps, please up vote and accept my answer :)